# A csv list of all AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am looking for csv list of all AWS services (I think there are 190 or so). I am getting a web list but need a csv for my analysis. Does anyone have a compiled csv, and can share that if possible?
Thanks much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: There was a mistake made by me(Thanks to @Mark B's warning). The working command is `aws service-quotas list-services`

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/service-quotas/list-service-quotas.html)

Comment: From the page you linked: "Lists the AWS services available in Service Quotas. Not all AWS services are available in Service Quotas."

Comment: The op said there are almost 190, the list provided +220 - i didn't have servicequotas:ListServices access on my account - so didn't check how many does it return @MarkB

Comment: @MarkB  `aws service-quotas list-services` returns 106 services, the answer i provided covers more than that. Also op didn't ask about the list of services available on service quotas.

Comment: there is no `aws list-services` command. The command you linked is `aws service-quotas list-services`.  Look at your link. If you try to run `aws list-services` it throws an error that the command doesn't exist, and then lists the AWS command line options available.

Comment: I understand, i didn't see the message printed `aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:` after i see the list of services printed as fallback. sorry for misunderstanding & thanks for info.

Comment: updated the answer @MarkB - thank you for the warning again.

Answer (score 0):

This would be very hard to produce a list of all AWS services.

AWS is releasing new services and features frequently, additionally some "services" actually cover a large number of sub features. Take for example SSM (Systems Manager), it covers a large number of solutions and is being expanded.

The best way of getting a "list" of all services would be accessing the https://aws.amazon.com/products/ page.